# How to create Social Login(Google, Facebook, Apple) API NodeJs Express REST for a React Native App?

Tags: node.js, react-native, express, facebook-login, google-signin

Is there any way to implement Social Login(Google, Facebook, Apple) API NodeJs Express REST for a React Native App, the way it's done for the web apps? How would you create API's??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install an npm package for social login on the frontend. Then you can pass the values that you wanted through the api to the backend.

Here's an example https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login